# jQuery slideDown() after hide and slideUp after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

How can i make the div #eFileStatus and #sFileStatus slideDown then wait 5 seconds and slideUp, this is my function which currently works and slides up after 5 seconds.

```
function changeShare(addr)
{
    var conf = confirm("Changing the share url will cause the previous URL to not be accessible\nAre you sure?");
    if(conf == true)
    {   
        // ajax request to change share url, create div after #key containing status message
        $.post("/var/jq/ajaxrequest.php", { changeShare: addr },
        function(data){
            $('#key').after('<div id="'+data.returnValue[0]+'FileStatus">'+data.returnValue[1]+'</div>');
        }, "json");
        // reload data in #key with new share url
        $("#key").load(window.location.pathname+" #key > *");
        // slideup the status message div
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#eFileStatus').slideUp();
            $('#sFileStatus').slideUp();        
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
        $("#eFileStatus, #sFileStatus").hide().slideDown(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#eFileStatus').slideUp();
                $('#sFileStatus').slideUp();        
            }, 5000);
        });
```

but this doesn't slide down and it also stops the sliding up.

Comment: why need hide() here ?

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for any errors? your code should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/fWZyT/ though a better approach would be to use `delay()`

Comment: @eicto you need to hide the elements because the `slideDown()` animation doesn't act on visible elements

Comment: @koala_dev even better for you approach : http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fWZyT/2/ :)

Comment: @eicto yes that's better :)

Comment: None of these fiddles are sliding down for me, only sliding up.

Comment: @user1869566 You are sure ? what browser ?

Comment: @user1869566 click the "Run" button on the top menu

Comment: works fine for me in firefox23 linux

Comment: when i run the function on my page for the first time after a new page load it doesn't work but when i run the function for the second time it does work.

Comment: are you trying to hide the divs and after 5sec display it again?

Comment: No i'm trying to show the div for 5 seconds, I'm pretty sure the problem lies with the ajax, i think it's trying to execute the slideDown before the div has been creating by the ajax response

Comment: @user1869566 can you show us how you're integrating the slide animation with the ajax call? are you using the callback for `load()`?

Comment: are the divs hidden in the first place?

Comment: Yes i am using load() but it has nothing to do with the div i want to slideDown, i managed to get it to work by placing everything inside the ajax response function so it waits for the response before sliding down.

Comment: @ShapCyber, no that's the problem the divs didn't exist because they were waiting for an ajax response before being created, thank you all for your help :)

Comment: guys i don't think this question make sense why will one applying function slide on undefined element.

Comment: @ShapCyber It's created by:

`$('#key').after('<div id="'+data.returnValue[0]+'FileStatus">'+data.returnValue[1]+'</div>');`

but because there's a delay whilst it waits for the data it tries to slideDown whilst it's not there. I placed the code for the slideDown inside the ajax response function and it now works. because it waits for the response before executing the function

Answer (score 2):

Okay i found the solution, as you can see i placed the slideDown inside the ajax function so it waits for the div to be created before trying to slideDown.

```
function changeShare(addr)
{
    var conf = confirm("Changing the share url will cause the previous URL to not be accessible\nAre you sure?");
    if(conf == true)
    {   
        // ajax request to change share url, create div after #key containing status message
        $.post("/var/jq/ajaxrequest.php", { changeShare: addr },
        function(data){
            $('#key').after('<div id="'+data.returnValue[0]+'FileStatus">'+data.returnValue[1]+'</div>');
            // reload data in #key with new share url
            $("#key").load(window.location.pathname+" #key > *");
            // slideup the status message div
            $("#eFileStatus, #sFileStatus").hide().slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();
        }, "json");
    }
}
```